# How to get full sql script with replaced wild cards in jdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have following code

```
public class Foo{

    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate nJdbcTemplate;

    public void bar(....){
         String query = "INSERT INTO ....
         ....
         nJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query, mapSqlParameterSourcesArray);
    }

}
```

I want to get full , valid insert SQL script to insert it into another database.

Is there way to achieve it in spring jdbc template?

Answer (score 0):

Not in the jdbc template.

It's not the jdbc template who's doing the placeholder replacement. It's the JDBC driver (or it could even be the database server!). Take a look at the [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) interface - the parameters are actually passed in different methods than the statement is.

(While this interface does not allow for named parameters, the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) states that Spring translates the named parameters to `?` making it suitable input for this interface.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Could you suggest any workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot provide a *good* workaround. This substitution is done in JDBC driver because it's not trivial (we're talking about SQL Injection and the likes here). A simple way would be to go through the statements and replace every `?` with the next argument, but 1) what about stirngs containing `?`, and 2) would you not be afraid of SQL injection?

Comment: If your use case is you want to retrieve the full SQL once it is performed in the database (not before / instead), you could try using the database's "query log" if the database supports such functionality (it's usually a table that contains all executed SQL statements, but most often this is turned off by default for obvious reasons.)

Comment: It sounds proper for me. I will investigate it in my postgresql